# Will load balancer having no instance in its subnet give error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I've been working for application setup via AWS. In brief my current infra is:

```
1 network load balancer available in 3 availability zones say us-west-2a,b and c

2 instances attached to elb in zones us-west-2a,b
```

In this case, will the requests would be sent to us-west-2c or the elb will automatically defer it since no instances are attached there.

Comment: Did you enable or disable Cross-zone load balancing for your NLB?

Comment: it's disabled for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have targets only in `us-west-2a,b`, then whether you have [Cross-Zone Load Balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/network-load-balancer-now-supports-cross-zone-load-balancing/) enabled or not, your NLB **will not direct traffic** to `us-west-2c` as it does not have any instances.

So to answer your question:

> will the requests would be sent to us-west-2c

No, they will **not** be sent there.

Comment: i think there is a typo, `Yes, they will be` -> Yes it will only if there are instances otherwise not